# How do you earn a hat when you have too much rep to do the action?

Tags: support, privileges, winter-bash

I was looking through [the different hats](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) that are available and saw that the **Carmen** hat can be earned if the following criteria is met:

> Suggest one or more edits that get approved during Winter Bash.

Since I have 2000+ rep, I can no longer request edits on the Stack Overflow site, since I can just edit a question directly now.

Does this mean that this hat is unavailable for me to earn on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You can likely still get it as long as you do not have *full* editing privileges, ie. are below [20k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: Even if you have 20k rep, just suggest an edit on a site where you don’t have that much rep. Earn the hat on another site and wear it network-wide. _Unless_, of course, you have ≥20k rep everywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How do you earn a hat when you have too much rep to do the action?

You don't. There are plenty of hats that are unobtainable when you have too little reputation. It's not the end of the world. Go for the ones that you *can* obtain.

> Now since I have 2000+ rep, I can no longer request edits on the StackOverflow site

That's not true. [Up to 20,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) you are able to suggest edits to tag wiki's and tag wiki excerpts.

Comment: This is a completionist's nightmare! How will I finish SO's winter bash now?!

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think of wiki edits, I could still suggest those edits. As for "There are plenty of hats that are unobtainable when you have too little reputation", you can earn reputation, if you'd really wanted to, 200 a day. I think the most you need is 3000, which is 15 days to earn all hats (non-secret) for a completionist. You can lose rep by posting crap, which is not encouraged.

Comment: If you post crap, I will steal your hats! @funie200

Comment: @CodyGray Of course I won't post crap. But what I was saying was that that would be the only way for a completionist to earn all hats if their rep is too high for certain actions, because you'll lose rep. And now also hats, which I guess is fair.

Comment: You could give bounties to reduce rep?

Comment: @sabik True, but there is also a ceiling for that. You can't have more than 3 active bounties at the same time and they are limited to 500 rep per bounty. The minimum duration of a bounty is 1 day, so you can give away 1500 reputation per day. Last winter bash ran for about 3 weeks, so for people with more than 33500 reputation (53500 for wiki edits), this is also not achievable. That is, for those who are willing to do this to begin with, which will be few if any.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - yes. Hat's are triggered by specific actions, and if you can't perform that action (e.g., have too much reputation, too little, are banned, etc), you can't get that specific hat.

You could always join another SE site and perform the action there. It won't get you the hat on Stack Overflow, but you will get another hat in your total hat count.

Comment: And with a possible exception of Glorfindel, no one will ever have more than 20000 rep on all 170-whatever sites :')